# How can I use AWS cognito to store my user specific keys?

Tags: encryption, amazon-cognito

I am implementing an application that allows users to send documents from user A to user B. I want to use client side encryption (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_encryption) to encrypt the document. Intermediately I store the encrypted document in S3 until user B logs in to download the document.

A strategy could be to encrypt the keys for client side encryption with the user password and use the password hash to match if the password is correct. This however raises problems when users forget their password.

Is there a way to 'attach' secret key information to the user profiles in aws cognito that will only become available once a user logs in? Bottom line it should not be possible for our administrators and developers to browse around in databases to collect the user keys and thus be able to decrypt the client side encrypted documents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, when creating a cognito user you can add custom attributes:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

After logging in and invoking any lambda, you can use the aws SDK to get these attributes.

Comment: Hi Jordi Tanta Diaz, thanks for your reply, much appreciated! I understand that I can add custom attributes. What is important for me is that those attributes only become available when the user logs in. When the user is not logged in, I don't want my administrators/developers be able to see this custom attributes. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, in fact this attribute could only be consulted from the AWS SDK as long as the credentials of the logged in user are passed, the moment you log out to the user, the backend will no longer have these credentials and will not be able to consult any of the attributes.
Anyway, remember that the attribute could be viewed from the UI of the Cognito UserPool, so if you want to add an extra level of security you could block access to this section of the AWS console.